# environment variables in google extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, process, service-worker, .env

I am trying to use environment variables in google extension. Can someone explain how to use it?

I tried the standard way, but `process` keyword is not available in google extension.it just gave me this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

I had a conversation with ChatGPT about this but it didn't help much. So if you encountered same problem, maybe you have solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way to use them directly. You'll have to write a separate utility and call it via nativeMessaging API.